# Where Is the AVD manager in android studio 4.0

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager, android-studio-4.0

I just updated my android studio to version 4.0.
Before the update (version 3.6), if I wanted to open the AVD manager all I needed to do was
 `Tools > AVD Manager`

Now I cannot open the avd manager with `Tools > AVD Manager` because the option is not there anymore

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds) all needed to be done is `Tools > AVD Manager`

**How it looks in Android studio:**

[image]

[image]

Where can I find the "AVD manager" option on android studio 4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated my answer. You can find here avd manager. [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but You are using android studio 3.6 version, my problem is with android studio 4.0 version

Comment: oh sorry, I gonna check it .

Answer (score 1):

On opening a project, the Tools menu initially does not contain the AVD Manager or SDK Manager entries.  Once the project has completed loading, these entries appear.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio Tools - AVD Manager menu]

Comment: This is another option you can use, nice